Flutter local notifications for sending notifications at multiple times from a start to an end date
I'm attempting to schedule multiple local notifications with different start and end dates using Flutter. Each notification should trigger daily at specific times between the start and end dates. Despite my efforts, I'm encountering difficulties. Can anyone provide guidance or assistance to help resolve this issue?
I want this
void scheduleMultipleNotifications() {
  // Initialize notification plugin

  // Define list of reminders with start date, end date, and time
  
  // Iterate over each reminder
    // Iterate over each day between start date and end date
      // Calculate scheduled time for notification
      
      // Schedule notification for this time
}

This is my code
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'package:local_notification_demo/logger.dart';
import 'package:local_notification_demo/model/set_time_model.dart';
import 'package:local_notification_demo/services/notification_service.dart';
import 'package:local_notification_demo/utils/date_format.dart';

class ScheduleBtn extends StatelessWidget {
  ScheduleBtn({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.setTimeModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function onTap;
  final SetTimeModel setTimeModel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      child: const Text('Schedule notifications'),
      onPressed: () {
        debugPrint(
            'Notifications Scheduled for ${setTimeModel.startDate ?? ""} ${setTimeModel.endDate ?? ""} ${setTimeModel.setTime}');
        Random random = Random();
        setTimeModel.id = random.nextInt(100);

        DateTime startDate = convertDateFormat(
            setTimeModel.startDate ?? "",
            AppDateFormats.dateFormatDDMMYYY,
            AppDateFormats.dateFormatYYYYMMDD);
        DateTime endDate = convertDateFormat(
            setTimeModel.endDate ?? "",
            AppDateFormats.dateFormatDDMMYYY,
            AppDateFormats.dateFormatYYYYMMDD);

        // Schedule notifications for each time in setTimeModel.setTime list
        // for (int i = 1; i <= setTimeModel.setTime.length; i++) {
        int hour = int.parse(setTimeModel.setTime[0]!.split(":")[0]);
        int minutes = int.parse(setTimeModel.setTime[0]!.split(":")[1]);
        NotificationService.scheduledNotification(
            setTimeModel.id,
            startDate,
            endDate,
            hour,
            minutes,
            setTimeModel.title ?? "",
            setTimeModel.setTime[0] ?? "");
        onTap();
      },
    );
  }

  DateTime convertDateFormat(
      String inputDateString, String inputFormat, String outputFormat) {
    try {
      var inputDate = DateFormat(inputFormat).parse(inputDateString);
      var outputDate = DateFormat(outputFormat).format(inputDate);
      return DateFormat(outputFormat).parse(outputDate);
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e("Error converting date format: $e");
      return DateTime.now();
    }
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:local_notification_demo/logger.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
  static final notificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static init() {
    notificationsPlugin.initialize(const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher'),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    ));
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
  }

  static checkPermission() {
    notificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestNotificationsPermission();
  }

  static void scheduledNotification(
    int id,
    DateTime startDate,
    DateTime endDate,
    int hour,
    int minutes,
    String title,
    String body,
  ) async {
    var androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel 65',
      'your channel name',
      importance: Importance.high,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
    );

    var notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidDetails,
    );

    tz.initializeTimeZones();

    for (DateTime date = startDate;
        date.isBefore(endDate.add(const Duration(days: 1)));
        date = date.add(const Duration(days: 1))) {
      DateTime scheduledTime =
          DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, hour, minutes);

      logger.e("scheduledTime=======${scheduledTime.toString()}");
      // Log selected date and time
      logger.d(
          'Scheduled notification for: ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm').format(scheduledTime)}');

      if (scheduledTime.isBefore(DateTime.now())) {
        scheduledTime = scheduledTime.add(const Duration(
            days: 1)); // Schedule for tomorrow if time is in the past
      }

      // Calculate the delay until the scheduled time
      int delay = scheduledTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch -
          DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

      try {
        await notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          id, // Unique ID for each notification
          title,
          body,
          tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(milliseconds: delay)),

          notificationDetails,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
          //notification to trigger even if the device is in idle/doze mode
        );
      } catch (e) {
        logger.e('Error scheduling notification: $e');
        // Handle the error here as needed
      }
    }
  }

  static cancelNotification(int notificationid) async {
    logger.e("cancle the notificationid id $notificationid");
    await notificationsPlugin.cancel(notificationid);
  }
}


you must explain the exact problem
